# TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined ,undefined error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
    const mongoClient=require('mongodb').mongoClient;
const state={
    db:null
}
module.exports.connect=function(done){
    const url='mongodb://localhost:27017'
    const dbname='shopping'

    mongoClient.connect(url,(err,data)=>{
        if(err) return done(err)
        State.db=data.db(dbname)
        done()
    })
}

module.exports.get=function(){
    return State.db
}
```

Getting this error when using this code, I would like to know what is causing the error and any possible fixes.

```
mongoClient.connect(url,(err,data)=>{
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
```

Not entirely sure what is causing this, I am using visual studio and have installed the latest version of mongodb.

Comment: mongoClient will be ```MongoClient```

```const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;```

Check out documentation at
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb#connect-to-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

db.mongoose
.connect(`mongodb://${dbConfig.HOST}:${dbConfig.PORT}/${dbConfig.DB}`, {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true
})

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the answer. Also, the question formatting is quite bad.